# Bootstrap 5, grid column H space and vertical fill?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would each column equally spaced. The `FORM` should fill in remaining vertical space.

What am I missing, exactly? I don't seem to have `ml-3`? Is it possible to make the gutter of columns, ZERO (so borders are all flush?) by default and expand it out using a single variable, as I've done in code below?

```
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Input"
                           aria-label="First name">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Input"
                           aria-label="Last name">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Last name"
                           aria-label="Last name">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic outlined example">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-white" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da">Overview<br><small>Hello</small></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-white" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da">Option Two</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-white" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da">Option Three</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-white" style="border: 1px solid #ced4da">Option Four</button>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3 mx-0 flex-grow-1">
                <div class="col-4 m-0 p-0 border rounded bg-white">
                    LIST
                </div>

                <div class="col-8 m-0 p-0 flex-grow-1">
                    <div class="row mb-3 mx-0 border rounded bg-white">
                        STEP
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3 mx-0 border rounded bg-white flex-grow-1">
                        FORM
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code?

Comment: Well, I removed all the text and cruft that I could. I tried isolating the FORM and STEP but removing the pretext fixed the problem. I managed to get the first column to go full vertical it's something to do with the nesting of the technique I copied. I think.

Comment: https://codepen.io/alex-barylski/pen/rNmaxgG

If thats any easier?

Comment: it's hard to tell w/o the outer container(s). The markup starts with `col` which would be in a `row`, but what about the row container?

Comment: I screwed up on the copy I think, the codepen.io example has the full markup, my bad